# Executing a string returned by a function as code

Tags: php, string, function, eval

I am trying to create a user-defined function that queries a table in my database, assesses the number of fields, and assigns each field to a variable.  I've been able to do that, but the return is a string that only displays as text, when I actually want it to execute as code.

Here's the code:

```
function query_function() { 
    $client_selected = "1";
    $name = "";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client_table WHERE client_id = '$client_selected'"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $num=mysql_num_fields($result);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $num) { 
        $name .= "$" . mysql_field_name($result, $i);
        $name .= " = $" . "row['" . mysql_field_name($result, $i) . "'];"; 
        $i++;
    } 
    return $name;
}
```

Comment: Have you read about [`arrays`](http://php.net/array) in PHP yet? Also why don't you just `foreach` over the `$row`?

Answer (score 1):

It would be much simpler to just:

```
extract(mysql_fetch_assoc($result), EXTR_SKIP);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Likewise you could do it the way you are like this:

```
$name = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
$$name = $row[$name];
```

For example:

```
$row = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
);
extract($row, EXTR_SKIP);
var_dump($a, $b, $c);

$name = 'd';
$$name = 4;
var_dump($d);
```

http://codepad.org/yvW0G8xc

Also note the the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Be very careful when using eval however. Only use it when when you're 100% sure what your query is pulling into the `$name` variable.

Comment: `eval` is not the best solution to his problem.